# Join two select queries

Tags: sql, firebird

I am trying to join two select queries. Here is my query.

```
(select 'stack' as id from RDB$DATABASE) t
inner join 
(select 'stack' as id from RDB$DATABASE) q 
on t.id=q.id
```

When I execute this query throws me error

```
Context: Statement::Prepare( (select 'stack' as id from RDB$DATABASE) t
inner join 
(select 'stack' as id from RDB$DATABASE) q 
on t.id=q.id )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed
SQL Message : -104
Invalid token
Engine Code    : 335544569
Engine Message :
Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -104
Token unknown - line 1, column 1
(
```

If I understand the error correctly, Firebird doesn't like '(' at the start of the query.

If so, how can I join two queries?

Answer (score 1):

The error *"Token unknown - line 1, column 1 ("* is returned because the presence of `(` in that location is unexpected. Your current query only has two sub-queries it is trying to join, but it is missing the `select` and `from` clauses. This makes it a syntactically invalid statement. See [SELECT](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-select) in the Firebird 2.5 Language Reference for the full syntax.

A valid query would be

```
select *
from (select 'stack' as id from RDB$DATABASE) t
inner join (select 'stack' as id from RDB$DATABASE) q 
  on t.id=q.id
```